# Получить родителя(.getParent) при инициализации(initialize) формы

Tags: java, javafx

```
public void btnAddDataClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    currentUser = (Users)btnAddData.getParent().getScene().getWindow().getUserData();
    System.out.println(currentUser);
}
```

В этом коде при помощи объекта кнопки я получаю getParent и нужный мне объект в getUserData, меня интересует как получить это во время инициализации:
`@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {`

Внутри этого метода я не нашел подходящего объекта чтоб взять getParent.
Много чего перепробовал, да и всемогущий гугл не помог.
*P.S. Заранее благодарен за помощь!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время вызова метода `initialize` вы никак не сможете получить `scene` ( чисто теоретически можете, но она будет null). Потому как сцена еще не проинициализирована.

Вам либо надо ждать, пока сцена появиться, и у нее забирать `window` и `userData` или же хранить пользовательские данные в каком-либо другом месте